# Sorting an Array Reference to Hashes

Tags: perl, arrays, reference, hash

After executing these lines in Perl:

```
my $data = `curl '$url'`;
my $pets = XMLin($data)->(pets);
```

I have an array reference that contains references to hashes:

```
$VAR1 = [
      {
        'title' => 'cat',
        'count' => '210'
      },
      {
        'title' => 'dog',
        'count' => '210'
      }
]
```

In Perl, how do I sort the hashes first by count and secondarily by title. Then print to STDOUT the count followed by the title on each newline.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you want counts in descending order and titles ascending:

```
print map join(" ", @$_{qw/ count title /}) . "\n",
      sort { $b->{count} <=> $a->{count}
                         ||
             $a->{title} cmp $b->{title} }
      @$pets;
```

That's compact code written in a functional style. To help understand it, let's look at equivalent code in a more familiar, imperative style.

Perl's [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) operator takes an optional SUBNAME parameter that allows you to factor out your comparison and give it a name that describes what it does. When I do this, I like to begin the sub's name with `by_` to make `sort by_...` ready more naturally.

To start, you might have written

```
sub by_count_then_title {
  $b->{count} <=> $a->{count}
              ||
  $a->{title} cmp $b->{title}
}

my @sorted = sort by_count_then_title @$pets;
```

Note that no comma follows the SUBNAME in this form!

To address another commenter's question, you could use `or` rather than `||` in `by_count_then_title` if you find it more readable. Both `<=>` and `cmp` [have higher precedence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity) (which you might think of as binding more tightly) than `||` and `or`, so it's strictly a matter of style.

To print the sorted array, a more familiar choice might be

```
foreach my $p (@sorted) {
  print "$p->{count} $p->{title}\n";
}
```

Perl uses `$_` if you don't specify the variable that gets each value, so the following has the same meaning:

```
for (@sorted) {
  print "$_->{count} $_->{title}\n";
}
```

The `for` and `foreach` keywords are synonyms, but I find that the uses above, *i.e.*, `foreach` if I'm going to name a variable or `for` otherwise, read most naturally.

Using `map`, a close cousin of `foreach`, instead isn't much different:

```
map print("$_->{count} $_->{title}\n"), @sorted;
```

You could also promote `print` through the `map`:

```
print map "$_->{count} $_->{title}\n",
      @sorted;
```

Finally, to avoid repetition of `$_->{...}`, the [hash slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) `@$_{"count", "title"}` gives us the values associated with count and title in the loop's current record. Having the values, we need to [join](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) them with a single space and append a newline to the result, so

```
print map join(" ", @$_{qw/ count title /}) . "\n",
      @sorted;
```

Remember that [`qw//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#qw%2fSTRING%2f) is shorthand for writing a list of strings. As this example shows, read a `map` expression back-to-front (or bottom-to-top the way I indented it): first sort the records, then format them, then print them.

You could eliminate the temporary `@sorted` but call the named comparison:

```
print map join(" ", @$_{qw/ count title /}) . "\n",
      sort by_count_then_title
      @$pets;
```

If the application of `join` is just too verbose for your taste, then

```
print map "@$_{qw/ count title /}\n",
      sort by_count_then_title
      @$pets;
```

Comment: What does "map" mean/do in the code above? And why didn't we need to specify the two attributes in two different sets of curly braces?

Comment: @syker : `map` takes each hash in your sorted array and prints its `count` and `title` values on a line, space-separated. @gbacon : It might be worth explaining if there is any difference between using `||` and `or` in your sort as I always see `||` in sort-by-anything examples. Is there a possibility that the more-readable `or` behaves differently under any circumstances?

Comment: @syker map is similar to a foreach.  check it out on perldoc (http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html)